# How to resolve NuGet Transitive Packages with vulnerabilities

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a project that requires the System.ServiceModel.Http NuGet package.

That particular package references 6 other packages transitively.

One of the transitive packages has an identified vulnerability (System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs).

I know I can promote the package to Top-level and then control the version. But my question is, is there any way to update the version of the transitive package without promoting it?

[image: screenshot]

The scenario I am trying to avoid is:

- MyProject references PackageA v1
- PackageA v1 references PackageB (which I then promote)
- PackageA v2 is released and it no longer depends on PackageB
- Now MyProject has an unnecessary reference to PackageB (which I have to remember to remove)

Comment: When you say "promoting" it I assume you mean taking a direct dependency, so you can specify the version explicitly. That works and feels to me like the obvious way of doing it - so what are you looking for in terms of a different solution?

Comment: Yes, that's fair, and that's what I meant by promoting it. What I was trying to avoid was a scenario like this:

- MyProject references PackageA v1
- PackageA v1 references PackageB (which I then promote)
- PackageA v2 is released and it no longer depends on PackageB
- Now MyProject has an unnecessary reference to PackageB (which I have to remember to remove)

Not a major issue. Just curious to see if there were any alternatives.

Comment: I would suggest updating the question to include the motivation. Personally I'd just add a comment in the project file for package A so that when you see you update it (either manually or via Renovate etc - because you'd still review that change in context) you'll be reminded to check whether you still need the package B dependency.

Comment: NuGet's "Central Package Management" (CPM) with transitive pinning does what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Directly Update Transitive Dependency:

Since you've identified that the vulnerability lies in the transitive package System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs, you can directly update its version to a fixed version that doesn't have the vulnerability.

Comment: That's what the OP says they already know about, but don't want to do.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).